# DDD bounded contexts and modules vs Symfony2 bundles

Tags: php, oop, symfony, architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to implement several concepts from domain driven design such as Bounded Contexts and modules.

I'm working on a Symfony2 project and I want to use a DDD approach to it. Symfony2 has bundles and each bundle has several folders for services, entities, controllers, views,..etc.

I want my application to have a layered approach like this one:
[image]

This is a single bounded context with its layers.

How can I map the bounded context, the layers and its modules to the bundles in Symfony2?

**Note**: I know DDD is more than a folder structure, but I want to resolve this certain issue here.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and you must) write your domain layer framework agnostic, so that you follow the DDD best practices and setup the folder the way structure you like. A good framework doesn't limit you with its own folder structure.
You can see bundles as an integration layer for your domain into Symfony.

With bundles basically just add:

- dependency injection around your domain layer
- add an persistence layer (Doctrine)
- add an HTTP layer
- configuration
- ...

I have a basic folder structure like this:

- src

  - Domain (everithing that is domain related)
  - DomainBundle (integration of the domain into Symfony - DI, configuration, concrete repository classes, entity mappings...)
  - WebBundle (controllers, forms, templates)

So you don't put domain logic into bundles. You just use them to add framework logic around your domain.